# ¿Cómo sustiutyo una columna en SQL según unos parámetros?

Tags: mysql, sql

estoy haciendo una aplicación sobre el cuidado de los abuelos y esta tiene una base de datos con una tabla, que son los tratamientos que los cuidadores han aplicado cada día.

Estaba buscando una forma de hacer que si en la misma fecha, que siempre será `CURDATE();`,
ya han sido registradas, en una columna, los tratamientos que se le han ejercido, se sustituya los nuevos tratamientos registrados y se borren los anteriores.

**Esta es la estructura:**
[image: Estructura de la tabka tratamientos]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes intentar a hacer esto utilizando una consulta SQL que actualice los registros existentes en lugar de insertar nuevos. Aquí hay un ejemplo de cómo podrías hacerlo con SQL, usando la función REPLACE o INSERT … ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE, asumiendo que tienes una clave primaria o única en tu tabla:

```
VALUES (CURDATE(), nuevoTratamiento1, nuevoTratamiento2, nuevoTratamiento3, idPaciente)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
tratamiento1 = VALUES(tratamiento1), 
tratamiento2 = VALUES(tratamiento2), 
tratamiento3 = VALUES(tratamiento3);
```